# Write NSMutableArray to plist not working

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, plist

I am using plists to save/load an NSMutableArray,

the code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *prsPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"records.plist"];

prs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:prsPath];
```

when I am using the last sentence of code somewhere else in my code it says: "prsPath" undeclared. (I am loading my code in ViewDidLoad) When I add an Object it doesn't save it, it doesn't even show up. (Loading the last sentence on add)

Comment: Your question is not clear. You are showing the code for reading, in the heading it says writing does not work. In the text you address an undeclared variable issue (something different altogether).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using this method and it's work 100%

```
- (void) writeToPlist: (NSString*)fileName withData:(NSMutableArray *)data
{
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *finalPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

     [data writeToFile:finalPath atomically: YES];
     /* This would change the firmware version in the plist to 1.1.1 by initing the NSDictionary with the plist, then changing the value of the string in the key "ProductVersion" to what you specified */
}
```

and this method for reading from plist file:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) readFromPlist: (NSString *)fileName {
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *finalPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

     BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:finalPath];

     if (fileExists) {
          NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
          return arr;
     } else {
          return nil;
     }
}
```

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

`[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:prsPath]` will *load* a plist ant initialize an array with it. Does you plist exist at that path already? You might also want to log the prsPath to see if it's correct.

Usually you would first check to see if a plist exists at the path by calling `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:prsPath]`. If it does not, you initialize an empty array.

Later you save it by calling `[prs writeToFile:prsPath atomically:YES]`.

Note that you can't initialize `NSMutableArrays` from plists. Arrays and dictionaries loaded from plists are always immutable. You would have to first load the plist into an `NSArray` and then initialize an `NSMutableArray` from that `NSArray`.

Comment: if I NSLog in ViewDidLoad it'll work but when I NSLog it somewhere else in my code it gives undeclared.

Comment: Well, is prsPath a strong/retained property of your view controller?

Comment: ;/ kidding me, I actually did forget that.